# Xcode 8.2 stopped providing crash reports?

Tags: xcode, crash-reports

In iTunes Connect I can see new crashes but if I Start the Organizer in Xcode to get the details there is nothing. Its like Xcode have stopped getting crash reports somewhere around change of the year and is several app-versions behind. Have someone experienced the same problem?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the local Organiser has always been only crashes you encountered — while attached or on a device that was subsequently attached. iTunes Connect has always been all reports that they've been able to collect from all users. So you could very easily see a mismatch between the two. Is my recollection at fault? Were the two joined together at some point?

Comment: No, the crashes from your device(s) are in Window->Devices. I'm speaking about Window->Organizer. There you have your Archives and corresponding Crashes. These crashes are fetched from iTunes Connect.

Comment: Then they have indeed changed that. Thank goodness I stuck with a comment and didn't attempt an answer!